# Using @@identity in a stored procedure good/bad?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that inserts a record which has Identity column.
Immediately after inserting I am using @@identity to insert a records in child table.

Are there any implications doing that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) should be used. If the INSERT should fire a trigger that also performs an identity insert, you'll get the wrong value (i.e., the value generated by the trigger's insert) from @@identity.

Answer (score 4):

It's usually not as good as `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, if your version offers this, because @@Identity isn't limited to the current scope.
It will retrieve the most recent identity even if it was from a different sp in a different table.

Pinal Dave has a straightforward explanation of the `IDENTITY` offerings here:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Answer (score 1):

@@IDENTITY is the last identity value inserted for ANY record. If you get high user concurrency, you're going to end up with the wrong identity value, i.e., you'll get a value which another request just inserted.

For the last identity value inserted in the current scope, use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/01/17/2736.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my favoriate artilce on this if for nothing else then for its title "[Identity Crisis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224821%28SQL.80%29.aspx)"